# ng circle progress not recognized as NgModule class

Tags: angular, ng-circle-progress

I'm trying to use the ng circle progress library in my Angular app (v.12.2.4.), however, when I tried importing this library on my app.module.ts I get the following error

'NgCircleProgressModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
ng-circle-progress.module.d.ts(4, 19): This likely means that the library (ng-circle-progress) which declares NgCircleProgressModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I have installed version1.6.0, as recommended here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress?activeTab=readme. However, when I tried importing this library on my app.module.ts I get the error mentioned earlier. After this, I uninstalled the 1.6.0 and tried all the other suggested versions but they all got the same error. Anyone knows how to fix this?